# error when creating a pipenv virtual environment with python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv

My OS is ubuntu 20.04 and my default python is 3.8.2. I'm trying to create a virtual environment with pipenv and python 3.7. The following error occurs when I run `pipenv install --python 3.7`:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3.7m (3.7.0) to create virtualenv…
⠋RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.7m with code 1 err: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py", line 16, in <module>\n    from distutils.command.install import SCHEME_KEYS\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'distutils.command\'\n'
Error while trying to remove the /home/yuhao/.local/share/virtualenvs/electrode-mimic-j_E-dTLW env: 
No such file or directory

Virtualenv location: 
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.7, but you are using None (/bin/python).
  $ pipenv check will surely fail.
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.8.2) to create virtualenv…
⠙created virtual environment CPython3.8.2.final.0-64 in 162ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/yuhao/.local/share/virtualenvs/electrode-mimic-j_E-dTLW, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, progress=latest, msgpack=latest, pytoml=latest, packaging=latest, setuptools=latest, contextlib2=latest, retrying=latest, pip=latest, pep517=latest, idna=latest, CacheControl=latest, appdirs=latest, requests=latest, pkg_resources=latest, webencodings=latest, distlib=latest, certifi=latest, distro=latest, ipaddr=latest, wheel=latest, six=latest, pyparsing=latest, urllib3=latest, chardet=latest, colorama=latest, lockfile=latest, html5lib=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/yuhao/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

Virtualenv location: /home/yuhao/.local/share/virtualenvs/electrode-mimic-j_E-dTLW
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
^C
Aborted!
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you install the python3-distutils package ?
If not you can install it with :

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```

If you need it for a python3 version that is not the system default, specify the python 3 version :

```
sudo apt-get install python3.X-distutils
```

*example: python3.8-distutils*

Comment: I did install it.

Comment: Did you install pipenv with pip ?

Comment: i installed it with pip

Comment: You could try to install python from source. Sometimes the python version shipped with ubuntu is buggy. See here for how to : https://realpython.com/installing-python/#how-to-build-python-from-source-code

Comment: I installed manually the 3.7.6 version and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 33):

I had the same error using Python 3.9.1, so I installed distutils with

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-distutils
```

and it works

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: Similar issue when making virtualenv for Python 3.10 under Ubuntu 20.04, resolved with
`sudo apt install python3.10-distutils`
The error message was `RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.10 with code 1 err: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py:16: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12.`

Answer (score 2):

You should try :

```
    pipenv lock --clear
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For python 11:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.11-distutils
```