# Why django is not installing on ubuntu?

Tags: django

I am trying to install django using pipenv but failing to do so.

```
 pipenv install django
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/djangoTry/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3.9 (3.9.5) to create virtualenv...
⠴ Creating virtual environment...RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.9 with code 1 err: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py", line 16, in <module>\n    from distutils import dist\nImportError: cannot import name \'dist\' from \'distutils\' (/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/__init__.py)\n'

✘ Failed creating virtual environment 

[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: 
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

Other info

```
python --version
Python 2.7.17
python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.4
pip3 --version
pip 21.1 from /home/aman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Please help.Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error when creating a pipenv virtual environment with python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64234182/error-when-creating-a-pipenv-virtual-environment-with-python-3-7)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with installing Django, is on creating your venv, I don't create on this way so I will pass the way that i create

Step 1 - Install pip

Step 2 - Install virtaulEnv

[check here how to install both](https://gist.github.com/Geoyi/d9fab4f609e9f75941946be45000632b)

after installed, `run python3 -m venv venv`this wil create an venv on your current directory. Initiate them with `. venv/bin/activate`and so run `pip install django`. That should work

Comment: Thanks @Dosbodoke. I will try it. Can you also tell that why pipenv is not working?

Comment: Sorry bro, I really has never used the pipenv method. Comment here if worked or not.

Answer (score -1):

Try pipenv install --python 3.9

Comment: this is not working. Again showing same error

Comment: didn't work for me as well